# I am not able to idenfiy the pins LED_PWM and LED_EN

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am working on turning broken laptop screen into a lamp by directly turning on only the backlight of the panel, I need to connect 12v to main power source (which I found), 5v to LED_PWM and 5v to LED_EN,
I am able to see their labels in the board but I cannot find them as the label is away from the PIN, I am not very experienced with electronics so I wasn't able to track their path and find, Can someone help me through the process to follow to be able to identify these pins so I can connect 5v input to them.
Thank you[image: You can see LED_EN on the bottom of the board beside the white wire, and LED_PWM in the very left of the board]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking for patterns in the SMD components that resemble the pattern of the far away silkscreen.

The text block on the left "C64, C65, ..." match with the three components on the bottom right of the large coil (the part with the "100" printed onto). So the only assumption I can make there is, that the test point I marked with the small arrow is the LED_EN signal.

The huge silkscreen block on the far right has to resemble both the two columns of unpopulated parts between the QFN-28 and the ribbon connector, as well as the block of smds right below the QFN. The hole pattern matches quite well, so the other via marked with the long arrow will be the LED_PWM signal.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to address this issue. Your diagnosis of the board's makes a lot of sense. Unfortunately, it still doesn't seem to work as expected. I plan to review the datasheet to verify the pin configuration and understand where else these pins are utilized. I will attempt to reroute my signal accordingly based on this information.

Comment: Hello Again sir, Apologies for my mistake, Your guess indeed was correct, I was doing a mistake before, My 5v weren't delivered correctly, but I then used an external 5V source and it worked fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Great, thanks for the feedback. Enjoy your light ;)